# Font looks pixelated on zoom

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am using a custom view and using canvas and paint to draw text. As this custom view 
supports zoom, font looks pixelated on zoom.

Its working OK android 2.3.6 but font is getting pixelated on higher versions(tested on 4.0.3)

2.3.6 is on Samsung ACE II and 4.0.3 is on SONY Tablet.

```
 public final Paint letterText = new Paint();
 letterText.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
 letterText.setColor(Color.BLACK);
 letterText.setAntiAlias(true);
 letterText.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);

 letterText.setTextSize(cellWidth * 0.75f) 
 FontMetrics fm = ds.letterText.getFontMetrics();
 float x = cellWidth /2 ;
 float y = cellHeight/2  - (fm.ascent + fm.descent ) /2;


 canvas.drawText(sb.toString(), x , y, letterText);
```